# RAILS 6 + Webpacker -- route error for packs/css|js/application-* in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, production-environment, webpacker

In development mode, all looks great. But when I switch over to production, bootstrap isn't found. When I look at the logs, I see errors like:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/js/application-2a5806e943e281221741.js"):
```

This is true for both CSS and JS. When I look inside public/packs the files do exist in the corresponding subdirectory (js for the .js file, etc). So, webpacker is did it's job but puma isn't finding it. Any ideas? This is an old rails app that was migrated up several versions of rails, so I'm sure there is something I missed when tying everything together.

Comment: did you set `config.public_file_server.enabled` to true  in production.rb ?

Comment: You have no idea how happy you've made me! That was set to whatever some environment var was set to...which obviously I hadn't set. It works just fine now!

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Tenzin's comment which I believe is the correct answer to the issue, Rails in development will always re-render assets and serve them. This is slow, but useful for seeing quick changes while developing.

When we want to deploy to production, the issue is Rails begins to serve static files which means that the server is no longer going to render them on every request. It will render them once and serve them forever. With webpacker, you can find the places these assets are served in webpacker.yml

```
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
```

So if you are deploying or trying to run production locally, first be sure to compile your assets for production so these static files are created.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Then make sure that wherever the server is running it has an ENV variable RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES set to anything. As you can see from production.rb,

```
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

Is simply checking if this variable is present. If it is then it will not re-render as we discussed and it will look for the static files shown in webpacker.yml.

As another small note, if you are using something like a React UI or Bootstrap and the CSS is missing, be sure that you are importing the CSS according to the library's documentation.

For example, in Bootstrap, you will need to create an application.scss file in app/javascript/packs/stylesheets (really wherever in the /javascript folder) and import that in /javascript/packs/application.js.

In application.scss you'll want to

```
import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

This is of course after you have added Bootstrap to your package.json with something like

```
yarn add bootstrap
```